# How can I find two mesurable functions satifying the following condition?

Tags: functions

I have the following problem:

> Give an example of mesurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n\stackrel{\lambda}{\rightarrow}f$ and $g_n\stackrel{\lambda}{\rightarrow}g$ but not $f_ng_n\stackrel{\lambda}{\rightarrow}fg$

They gave us the hint to take $f_n=\frac{1}{n}\left(\chi_{(0,n)}\right)$. I don't know how to find my f and also my $g_n$ could someone give me a hint, this would be very nice.

Thank you!

Comment: What does the $\lambda$ mean, convergence in Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yes thank you!!